# How can I hide application cache events in the console?

Tags: google-chrome, logging, console, html5-appcache

I get many

> Application Cache Checking event

console entries and similar, including for pages that I am not touching when refreshing others. This is very distracting while I am debugging a multi-player game across several tabs. I'd prefer the log to not change or move while I am not active in that tab.

Is there a way to stop Chrome from spamming these events into my console?

Comment: Just checking if you found a solution for this outside Stackoverflow (I also find it very distracting!).

Comment: No, I have not. Although, I have created a simple html page with iframes for the two pages I was testing. It has the disadvantage of merging both consoles into one, but for my purposes it is suitable. Unfortunately I have discovered many issues with Chrome which are persisting sometimes for years with complete silence or denial from Google. Not a good sign fro ma dev perspective.

Answer (score 2):

When in chrome, right click inside the console select: filter -> "Hide Messages from app" this will hide all those irrelevant messages.

Answer (score 2):

You can hit the **filter button** and use a **regular expression** (in Chrome Canary onwards) to *exclude* all messages that contain a phrase:

[image]

The regex that suited me was:

```
^(?!.*?Application Cache)
```

You will almost certainly need to tweak it for your needs (maybe not starting at the beginning of a line, case insensitive etc.) so do a search for "*regex builder online*" and you'll find quite a few tools to help you narrow down the exact one for you.

The regex above may be broken down like this (courtesy of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)):
[image]

Comment: Why is `?!.*?` required to work? I mean, this works just fine in node: `/^Application Cache/.test("Application Cache does a thing\n") == true`...but not in the filter. :/

Comment: @ingwie-phoenix, I've edited my answer to also show a breakdown of that regex. Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot for that - that actually explains a lot :) Thanks!

Comment: +1. In today's stable versions of Chrome, this needs to be surrounded by the regex delimiters - i.e. `/^(?!.*?Application Cache)/`